# What is postorder traversal on this simple tree?

Tags: algorithms, trees

Given the following tree:

[image: tree]

Which traversal method would give as result the following output: CDBEA?

The answer in my study guide is *Postorder*, but I think postorder would output: DEBCA. Am I wrong?

Comment: Which book are you referencing? "The book" does not make sense without context.

Comment: In fact is a study guide and this is a question that's why there is no context

Comment: This is random traversal :) what is the usage?

Comment: The question is fine (though it might be better to generalize it a little bit so it is more useful for others also), it is a normal question a CS student might ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not wrong.

A *postorder*  traversal visits the left subtree, then the right subtree, then the root of the current tree (recursively).

Comment: perfect I just wanted to be sure, thanks

Comment: Unordered children *could* explain why C comes first, but not the position of B.

Comment: I can't make sense of the traversal CDBEA. Is this just random? If not, what sort of traversal is being used?